# Solr Spell Checker Language Support

Tags: solr

Does Solr spell checker gives suggestion for other languages?

Answer (score 0):

The solr spellchecker is based solely on what you have indexed, not based on some dictionary of "correct" words.

So yes, it supports whatever language you index your stuff in.

Answer (score 0):

Solr's best practice of handling multiple languages per index is to have a separate set of fields per language.  So you'd have fields named text_en, title_en, etc. for English and text_de, title_de, tec. for German.  A different instance of spellchecker component must be used for a field.  (Usually, *_en fields will be combined to one field, say textSpell_en, using copyField operator.) Now the question is, can Solr allows multiple instances of spellchek components? I think it does but I don't know for sure.  Has anyone done this?